# create associative array from simple array, auto increment key for each array item

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a simple array in the format `$arr = array(a,b,c,d);` that is dynamically populated.

How would I convert this into an associative array like

```
$newarr = array(
    'embedCode0' => a,
    'embedCode1' => b,
    'embedCode2' => c,
    'embedCode3' => d
    );
```

I know I can already access `b` in `$arr` with `$arr[1]` but I am passing `$newarr` from PHP to Javascript and accessing the array items in JS using `phpVars.embedCode0`, `phpVars.embedCode1` etc

I have tried to access the items from `$arr` in JS using `phpVars[0]` and `phpVars.[0]` but neither method works so I think I need to create the associative array with the key values in PHP first.

Comment: How are you passing $newarr from PHP to Javascript?

Comment: I am using the Worpress `wp_localize_script` function to pass the array to Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an associative array like that:

```
$newarr = array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
    $newarr["embedCode$key"] = $value;

}
```

Comment: the `$i`/`$i++` is not needed if you use the key from `$arr` -> `foreach($arr as $key=>$value){$newarr["embedCode$key"] = $value;}`

Answer (score -1):

array_flip will do

```
$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow");
$result=array_flip($a1);
print_r($result);
```